# How do you filter Strapi results on properties multi levels deep?

Tags: strapi, nuxt-strapi

I am trying to filter results from Strapi based on fields that are multi levels deep and I can't get it to work.
A find all on something returns this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "Name": "Batch Brewing Company",
            "Address": "44 Sydenham Rd Marrickville NSW 2204",
            "Phone": "(02) 9550 5432",
            "Location": {
                "geohash": "r3grpfdckvw1",
                "coordinates": {
                    "lat": -33.9118039304194,
                    "lng": 151.16487711668017
                }
            },
            "createdAt": "2023-08-09T08:03:49.382Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-09T08:03:52.884Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-08-09T08:03:52.877Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "Name": "Willie the Boatman",
            "Address": "75 Mary St St Peters NSW 2044",
            "Phone": "0285567528",
            "Location": {
                "geohash": "r3gx042sxfhj",
                "coordinates": {
                    "lat": -33.91263754768333,
                    "lng": 151.1728996038437
                }
            },
            "createdAt": "2023-08-09T08:15:19.860Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-09T08:15:21.024Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-08-09T08:15:21.022Z"
        }
    }
],
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 25,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "total": 2
    }
}
}
```

If I filter on anything in the top level it works. Name for example. Even if I filter Location on a property inside it, that works. For example:
[http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/distributors?filters[Location][$contains]=r3grpfdckvw1](http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/distributors?filters%5BLocation%5D%5B$contains%5D=r3grpfdckvw1)

But when I try to filter on the properties below Location it doesn't work. This returns all results:
[http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/distributors?filters[Location][geohash][$contains]=r3grpfdckvw1](http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/distributors?filters%5BLocation%5D%5Bgeohash%5D%5B$contains%5D=r3grpfdckvw1)

How can I filter based on deeper level properties?

I'm using Nuxt Strapi so I'm also trying it with that I have the same thing.

This works:

```
const { find } = useStrapi();
const response = await find('distributors', {filters: {Location: {$null: true}}  });
```

This doesn't work:

```
const { find } = useStrapi();
const response = await find('distributors', {filters: {Location: {geohash: {$null: true}}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate whatever nested property you're trying to filter or access.

By default, Strapi does not populate relations, components, media files, or dynamic zones.
If you want to populate the `Location` component, you can add `populate=Location`, which will only populate the first level of `Location`, and you can populate nested properties like this `populate=Location.coordinates` or using [LHS Brackets Notation](https://christiangiacomi.com/posts/rest-design-principles/#lhs-brackets) which is recommended by Strapi. [See Strapi docs for populating and deep populating examples](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#populate-2-levels)

Now since you want to filter by `Location.geohash`, [you have to populate it first](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/filters-locale-publication#deep-filtering) with `populate[0]=Location`.
Here's how your request URL would look like:
`http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/distributors?populate[0]=Location&filters[Location][geohash][$contains]=r3grpfdckvw1`